# How to get the list of possible operational attributes for an objectClass with python-ldap?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

With this python snippet, I can get the list of all the available objectClasses in a LDAP server:

```
import ldap

conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://127.0.0.1:389")
conn.simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=tld", "mypassword")
res = conn.search_s("cn=subschema", ldap.SCOPE_BASE, "(objectclass=*)", ["*", "+"])
subschema_entry = res[0]
subschema_subentry = ldap.cidict.cidict(subschema_entry[1])

subschema = ldap.schema.SubSchema(subschema_subentry)
object_class_oids = subschema.listall(ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass)
object_classes = [subschema.get_obj(ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass, oid) for oid in object_class_oids]
```

From this point this is easy to get all the required and optional attributes with `object_class.may` and `object_class.must`, but how can I get the list of the operational attributes applicable on a given objectClass? For instance the `memberof` attribute brought by the `memberof` OpenLDAP overlay, or the `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute brought by the `ppolicy` overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operational attributes are maintained by the LDAP server. They are not "applicable on a given objectClass". Thus they must not be set by user applications and they are not referenced in object class descriptions.

You can look at the instance attribute `AttributeType.usage` which contains an Integer indicating its usage.

See also:

- [RFC 4512 -- Operational Attributes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-3.4)
- [ldap.schema.models -- dict AttributeUsage used in AttributeType](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/9dd59a9cefdf8980beca5d75ac5983fdde7f0d79/Lib/ldap/schema/models.py#L183)